# Getting start and end of tokens in string with regular expressions

Tags: c, regex, syntax-highlighting

I am trying to implement some kind of syntax highlighting for C programs in C itself. Imagine I have stored all the source code I want to highlight into a string, and before printing it, I would like to know what color to use for each token.

I know I can use `<regex.h>` to **test** regular expressions, but I am not sure how to **find** the positions of matching expressions in a string.

Imagine I had the following input code:

```c
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int var = my_func("Hello, world.");
    return 0;
}
```

And I want to render it with colors, just like it's shown in the code block above.

What I would want is to be able to test some expressions in the string, and get a pointer (or position) in the string where the first match **ends**. So I would start by testing `int main(int [...]`, and the first match would be the `int` keyword, which ends at position 3. Then I could keep checking from there, and so on.

It's the first time I have to deal with something like this, so if anyone knows a better method, please let me know.

Comment: Specifically regarding [`<regex.h>`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/regex.h.html): have you read [the manual for `regexec`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/regexec.html)? It describes in detail how the `pmatch` argument is used to provide start & end offsets for the subexpressions matched by the pattern.

Comment: @Oka I am looking at the documentation, but there is something I don't quite get. If the item filled at `pmatch[0]` is supposed to be "the substring that corresponds to the entire regular expression", the first real match should be `pmatch[1]`, so the caller must allocate a `regmatch_t pmatch[2]` array if he wants to check for an expression with a single group, right? In that case, what should I use as `nmatch` argument, 1 or 2? Since it says: "the application shall ensure that the pmatch argument points to an array with at least nmatch elements"

Comment: The simple way to think about it: `pmatch` should always have at least `nmatch` number of elements (i.e., `regmatch_t [nmatch]`). `nmatch=0` means you want no match data (see also: `REG_NOSUB`), `nmatch=1` means you want only the entire expression match, `nmatch>=2` starts to include subexpression matches.

Comment: Perfect, I get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the source code loaded in a `char` array, you might consider writing a `get_token()` function that returns the token type and length.  Depending on the token type, you output the corresponding color and the token source using:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum tokenType {
    END, WHITESPACE, NEWLINE, COMMENT, PREPROCESSOR,
    KEYWORD, IDENTIFIER, STRING, CHARCONST, NUMBER, OPERATOR,
    OTHER
};

struct parse_context {
    const char *filename;
    const char *source;
    size_t source_pos;
    int line_number;
    int column_number;
    int at_bol;
    ...
};

const char *colors[] = {
    [END] = ...,
    [WHITESPACE] = ...,
    [NEWLINE] = ...,
    [COMMENT] = ...,
    [PREPROCESSOR] = ...,
    [KEYWORD] = ...,
    [IDENTIFIER] = ...,
    [STRING] = ...,
    [CHARCONST] = ...,
    [NUMBER] = ...,
    [OPERATOR] = ...,
    [OTHER] = ...,
};

enum tokenType get_token(struct parse_context *pc,
                         const char *s, int *token_len) {
    ...
}

void my_func(const char *filename, const char *s) {
    struct parse_context ctx = {
        filename, s, 0, 1, 1, 1,
    };
    enum tokenType last_token = END;

    for (;;) {
        int len;
        enum tokenType tok_type = get_token(&ctx, s, &len);
        if (tok_type != last_token) {            
            printf("%s", colors[tok_type]);
            last_token = tok_type;
        }
        if (tok_type == END) {
            break;
        } else {
            printf("%.*s", len, s);
            s += len;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a quick parser I wrote to colorize C source code my way:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Parse C tokens.

// XXX: no support for UTF-8 identifiers
// XXX: no support for universal-character-name in identifiers

enum c_token_type {
    END, WHITESPACE, NEWLINE, COMMENT, PREPROCESSOR,
    KEYWORD, IDENTIFIER, STRING, CHARCONST, NUMBER, OPERATOR,
    CTYPE, FUNCALL, OTHER, ERROR,
};

struct c_parse_context {
    const char *filename;
    const char *source;
    const char *p;
    const char *token_start;
    char token_string[80];
    int line_number;
    int column_number;
    int at_bol;
    int in_preprocess;
    //...
};

static const char c_keywords[] =
    " auto break case const continue default do else enum extern for "
    " goto if inline register restrict return sizeof static struct "
    " switch typedef union volatile while "
    /* types */
    " char double float int long unsigned short signed void "
    /* C99 and C11 keywords */
    " _Alignas _Alignof _Atomic _Generic _Noreturn _Static_assert "
    " _Thread_local "
    /* C99 and C11 types */
    " _Bool _Complex _Imaginary "
    /* C23 keywords */
    " alignas alignof constexpr false nullptr static_assert thread_local "
    " true typeof typeof_unqual "
    /* C23 types */
    " bool _BitInt _Decimal128 _Decimal32 _Decimal64 "
    ;

static const char c_types[] =
    /* types */
    " char double float int long unsigned short signed void va_list "
    /* C99 and C11 types */
    " _Bool _Complex _Imaginary "
    /* C23 types */
    "  bool _BitInt _Decimal128 _Decimal32 _Decimal64 "
    /* common standard types */
    "  FILE va_list "
    ;

static const char c_punctuators[] =
    " [ ] ( ) { } . -> ++ -- & * + - ~ ! / % << >> < > <= >= == != ^ | "
    " && || ? : :: ; ... = *= /= %= += -= <<= >>= &= ^= |= , # ## "
    " <: :> <% %> %: %:%: ";

static int c_find_word(const char *words, const char *s, int len) {
    for (const char *p = words; (p = strchr(p, *s)) != NULL; p++) {
        if (p[-1] == ' ' && !strncmp(p, s, len) && p[len] == ' ')
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

static int c_is_keyword(const char *s, int len) {
    return c_find_word(c_keywords, s, len);
}

static int c_is_type(const char *s, int len) {
    return c_find_word(c_types, s, len)
    ||     (len > 2 && s[len - 2] == '_' && s[len - 1] == 't');
}

static int c_getc(struct c_parse_context *pc) {
    for (;;) {
        int c = (unsigned char)*pc->p++;
        if (c == '\0') {
            pc->p--;
            return 0;
        }
        if (c == '\r') {  // convert end of line sequences to '\n'
            if (*pc->p == '\n')
                pc->p += 1;
            return '\n';
        }
#if 0   // trigraphs can be handled here.
        if (c == '?' && *pc->p == '?') {
            switch (pc->p[1]) {
            case '=':  c = '#';  pc->p += 2; break;
            case '(':  c = '[';  pc->p += 2; break;
            case '/':  c = '\\'; pc->p += 2; break;
            case ')':  c = ']';  pc->p += 2; break;
            case '\’': c = '^';  pc->p += 2; break;
            case '<':  c = '{';  pc->p += 2; break;
            case '!':  c = '|';  pc->p += 2; break;
            case '>':  c = '}';  pc->p += 2; break;
            case '-':  c = '~';  pc->p += 2; break;
            }
        }
#endif
        if (c == '\\') {  // remove escaped newlines
            if (*pc->p == '\n') {
                pc->p++;
                continue;
            }
            if (*pc->p == '\r') {
                pc->p++;
                if (*pc->p == '\n')
                    pc->p++;
                continue;
            }
        }
        return c;
    }
}

static int c_peekc(struct c_parse_context *pc) {
    const char *start = pc->p;
    int c = c_getc(pc);
    pc->p = start;
    return c;
}

static int c_peekc2(struct c_parse_context *pc) {
    const char *start = pc->p;
    int c = c_getc(pc);
    c = c_getc(pc);
    pc->p = start;
    return c;
}

static inline int c_isalnum_(int c) {
    return isalnum(c) || c == '_';
}

static int c_parse_number(struct c_parse_context *pc, int lastc) {
    /* parse a pp-number, the grammar allows for invalid numbers */
    int c;
    for (; (c = c_peekc(pc)) != '\0'; lastc = c, c_getc(pc)) {
        if (!c_isalnum_(c) && c != '.') {
            if (c == '+' || c == '-') {
                if (!memchr("eEpP", lastc, 4))
                    break;
            } else
            if (c == '\'') { // C23 digit separators
                if (!c_isalnum_(c_peekc2(pc)))
                    break;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return NUMBER;
}

static int c_parse_string(struct c_parse_context *pc, int sep) {
    int c;
    while ((c = c_peekc(pc)) != '\0' && c != '\n') {
        c_getc(pc);
        if (c == sep)
            return (sep == '\'') ? CHARCONST : STRING;
        if (c == '\\' && c_getc(pc) == '\0')
            break;
    }
    // unterminated string or character constant
    return ERROR;
}

static int c_parse_operator(struct c_parse_context *pc, int c) {
    const char *save[4];
    size_t len = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0;;) {
        pc->token_string[i] = (char)c;
        save[i] = pc->p;
        i++;
        if (c_find_word(c_punctuators, pc->token_string, i))
            len = i;
        if (i == 4 || !ispunct(c = c_getc(pc)))
            break;
    }
    if (len) {
        pc->p = save[len - 1];
        pc->token_string[len] = '\0';
        return OPERATOR;
    } else {
        pc->p = save[0];
        return OTHER;
    }
}

static int c_parse_comment1(struct c_parse_context *pc) {
    int c;
    while ((c = c_peekc(pc)) != '\0' && c != '\n') {
        c_getc(pc);
    }
    return COMMENT;
}

static int c_parse_comment2(struct c_parse_context *pc) {
    int c;
    while ((c = c_peekc(pc)) != '\0') {
        c_getc(pc);
        if (c == '*' && c_peekc(pc) == '/') {
            c_getc(pc);
            return COMMENT;
        }
    }
    // unterminated comment
    return ERROR;
}

static int c_parse_identifier(struct c_parse_context *pc, int c) {
    size_t len = 0;
    pc->token_string[len++] = (char)c;
    while (c_isalnum_(c = c_peekc(pc))) {
        if (len < sizeof(pc->token_string) - 1)
            pc->token_string[len++] = (char)c;
        c_getc(pc);
    }
    pc->token_string[len] = '\0';
    if (c_is_type(pc->token_string, len))
        return CTYPE;
    if (c_is_keyword(pc->token_string, len))
        return KEYWORD;
    if (isblank(c))
        c = c_peekc2(pc);
    if (c == '(')
        return FUNCALL;
    return IDENTIFIER;
}

enum c_token_type c_get_token(struct c_parse_context *pc) {
    int c, c1, c2;

    pc->token_start = pc->p;
    c = c_getc(pc);

    if (isspace(c)) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            pc->at_bol = 1;
            pc->in_preprocess = 0;
            return NEWLINE;
        }
        while (memchr(" \t\f\v", c_peekc(pc), 4)) {
            c_getc(pc);
        }
        return WHITESPACE;
    }

    if (pc->at_bol) {
        pc->at_bol = 0;
        if (c == '#') {
            pc->at_bol = 0;
            pc->in_preprocess = 1;
            return PREPROCESSOR;
        }
    }

    switch (c) {
    case '\0':
        return END;
    case '/':
        if (c_peekc(pc) == '/') {
            c_getc(pc);
            return c_parse_comment1(pc);
        }
        if (c_peekc(pc) == '*') {
            c_getc(pc);
            return c_parse_comment2(pc);
        }
        break;
    case '.':
        if (isdigit(c_peekc(pc)))
            return c_parse_number(pc, c);
        break;
    case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
    case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
        return c_parse_number(pc, c);
    case '\'':
    case '\"':
        return c_parse_string(pc, c);
    case 'L':
    case 'U':
        if ((c1 = c_peekc(pc)) == '\'' || c1 == '\"')
            return c_parse_string(pc, c_getc(pc));
        break;
    case 'u':
        if ((c1 = c_peekc(pc)) == '8' && ((c2 = c_peekc2(pc)) == '\'' || c2 == '\"')) {
            c_getc(pc);
            return c_parse_string(pc, c_getc(pc));
        }
        if (c1 == '\'' || c1 == '\"')
            return c_parse_string(pc, c_getc(pc));
        break;
    }
    // XXX: should handle UTF-8 and universal-character-name here
    if (c_isalnum_(c))
        return c_parse_identifier(pc, c);
    return c_parse_operator(pc, c);
}

// C token colorizer

// ANSI colors
#define RESET          "\033[0m"
#define BLACK          "\033[30m"
#define RED            "\033[31m"
#define GREEN          "\033[32m"
#define YELLOW         "\033[33m"
#define BLUE           "\033[34m"
#define MAGENTA        "\033[35m"
#define CYAN           "\033[36m"
#define WHITE          "\033[37m"
#define GREY           "\033[90m"
#define BRIGHT_RED     "\033[91m"
#define BRIGHT_GREEN   "\033[92m"
#define BRIGHT_YELLOW  "\033[93m"
#define BRIGHT_BLUE    "\033[94m"
#define BRIGHT_MAGENTA "\033[95m"
#define BRIGHT_CYAN    "\033[96m"
#define BRIGHT_WHITE   "\033[97m"
#define DEFAULT  BRIGHT_GREEN

const char * const c_colors[] = {
    [END] = RESET,
    [WHITESPACE] = DEFAULT,
    [NEWLINE] = RESET,
    [COMMENT] = WHITE,
    [PREPROCESSOR] = CYAN,
    [KEYWORD] = BRIGHT_WHITE,
    [IDENTIFIER] = DEFAULT,
    [STRING] = BRIGHT_CYAN,
    [CHARCONST] = BRIGHT_CYAN,
    [NUMBER] = GREEN,
    [OPERATOR] = DEFAULT,
    [CTYPE] = BRIGHT_MAGENTA,
    [FUNCALL] = BRIGHT_YELLOW,
    [OTHER] = RED,
    [ERROR] = RED,
};

void c_colorize(const char *filename, const char *source) {
    struct c_parse_context ctx = {
        filename, source, source, NULL, { 0 }, 1, 1, 1, 0,
    };
    enum c_token_type last_color = END;

    for (;;) {
        enum c_token_type tok_type = c_get_token(&ctx);
        const char *s = ctx.token_start;
        int len = ctx.p - s;
        enum c_token_type color = tok_type;
        if (ctx.in_preprocess && tok_type != COMMENT) {
            color = PREPROCESSOR;
        }
        if (last_color != color) {
            if (c_colors[color]) {
                fputs(c_colors[color], stdout);
            }
            last_color = color;
        }
        if (tok_type == END) {
            break;
        } else {
            printf("%.*s", len, s);
            s += len;
        }
    }
}

char *load_file(const char *filename, FILE *fp) {
    char buf[4096];
    char *source = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    size_t nread;
    FILE *fp_close = NULL;

    if (fp == NULL) {
        fp = fopen(filename, "r");
        if (fp == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n",
                    filename, strerror(errno));
            return NULL;
        }
        fp_close = fp;
    }
    while ((nread = fread(buf, 1, sizeof buf, fp)) > 0) {
        char *new_buf = realloc(source, len + nread + 1);
        if (new_buf == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "out of memory for %s\n", filename);
            free(source);
            source = NULL;
            break;
        }
        source = new_buf;
        memcpy(source + len, buf, nread);
        len += nread;
        source[len] = '\0';
    }
    if (fp_close)
        fclose(fp_close);
    return source;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc > 1) {
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            char *source = load_file(argv[i], NULL);
            if (source) {
                c_colorize(argv[i], source);
                free(source);
            }
        }
    } else {
        char *source = load_file("<stdin>", stdin);
        if (source) {
            c_colorize("<stdin>", source);
            free(source);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like this approach, but the `get_token` function doesn't check for "context" (using a different color for function declarations: `TYPE func_name(...)`). I think the concept is good enough for what I need, though.

Comment: @trxgnyp1: good point. A context is needed for that if you want to colorize function definitions and/or function calls... Context is actually required to distinguish `#` as introducing a preprocessor directive vs used in macro expansions  for stringization and.or token pasting.

Comment: Ah, I didn't even think about `#` inside macros. I guess I could just "match" for preprocessor directives altogether, like `#include` and `#define`, and just use the default colors for the rest of the `#`.

Comment: @trxgnyp1 Since you're parsing C code you might want to take comments as well as string literals into account.

Comment: @trxgnyp1: I updated my answer with a full parser.  It handles most cases but does not keep escaped newlines in source form so the output is not strictly identical to the source input.  I shall try and fix this if I don't fall asleep :)

Comment: @chqrlie Holy... Thank you so much, I will try it soon.

Comment: @trxgnyp1: I updated the answer with a better version: fixed some bugs and handle escaped newlines non destructively.

Comment: @chqrlie I tried it today, and it's perfect. I will have to modify some stuff to adapt it to my main program, but it helped me a lot. Thank you again!